# Help to Matching the two different Object Records?

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

Could anyone help me to matching the field with two different objects

1.I Have two objects 1.Case 2.custom object Integration__c.here i'm tring to get
  the matching the some fields of both objects.

2.Case object fields for matching AccountName and IntegrationTo__c and 
  Integration__c object fields are account__c,integrationwith__c.

3.if the both object fields are matching then get the record details from 
  Integration__c custom object.

for that i have developed a trigger as after insert on Case object.

```
trigger IntegrationType on Case (after Insert) {

List<ID> cIds = new List<ID>();

//List<Integration__c> integ = new List<Integration__c>();

for(Case cObj : Trigger.new){

      if(cObj.Account.Name != null && cObj.IntegrationTo__c != null){
        cIds.add(cObj.Id); //add case ids.
    }     

}

List<Integration__c> ll  =  [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,account__c,integrationwith__c FROM Integration__c  WHERE Id=:cIds]; 

for(Integration__c lst : ll){

    if(!cIds.isEmpty()){


       //help me here how to match the fields

        String uname = lst.username__c;
        String pwd= lst.password__c;
        String url= lst.URL__c;

        System.debug('Username :' +uname);
        System.debug('Username :' +pwd);
        System.debug('Username :' +url);
  }
} 

}
```

Comment: How Integration__c is related to Case object? I can see you are querying List<Integration__c> with the CaseIds as Id value of CaseIds, which will never match

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that Integration__c object has a lookup field relating to Case (Case__c)

You can filter the list based on SOQL query and that will be easy to achieve like this:

```
for(Case cObj : Trigger.new){
      if(cObj.Account.Name != null && cObj.IntegrationTo__c != null){
        cIds.add(cObj.Id); //add case ids.
    } 
}

List<Integration__c> ll  =  [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,account__c,integrationwith__c 
                            FROM Integration__c  
                            WHERE Case__c IN:cIds
                            AND Case__r.AccountId = account__c
                            AND Case__r.IntegrationTo__c = integrationwith__c ]; 


 for(Integration__c lst : ll){
        //do your stuff here

    }
```

Comment: last `if` is unnecessary as final for loop will do nothing if list is empty

Comment: thats why I have removed that last if condition

Comment: sorry - I was unclear, the `if(!ll.isEmpty())` is unnecessary

Comment: yes, let me remove this. you are correct

Comment: Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'account__c' at line 13 column 54        here i passed like this  :   Case__r.AccountName = :account__c AND Case__r.IntegrationTo__c = :integrationwith__c    Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist:  account__c at line 13 column 64