# Case field mapping with custom object fields?

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

i have posted this question earlier but i'm not getting the proper solution

- please read the requirement carefully.*

  i have a custom object Integration__c and it has fields username__c,password__c,url__c,account__c(lookup field) fields.
  and Integration__c has some records.

here comes my requirement is i have created a trigger on Case object as after insert event.

1.when case creating must be select an account lookup field with one
salesforce account.

2.now after clicking the save button it will check with Integration__c
custom object records with the matching account field in case record.

3.if any record is in the Integration__c is match with the case object account field then returns the field values of integration__c from that record only.

### for that i have developed a trigger on Case :

```
trigger Type on Case (after Insert) {

    List<ID> cIds = new List<ID>();
     
    Set<String> lst_accountName = new Set<String>();
    List<String> allaccountnamesList = new List<String>();
    
    //Map<ID, Integration__c> mapIds = new Map<ID,  Integration__c>();
    
            
        for(Case cObj : Trigger.new){
        
              if(cObj.Account.Name != null && cObj.IntegrationTo__c != null){
              
                cIds.add(cObj.Id);  
               
             } lst_accountName.add(cObj.Account.Name); 
             
        }allaccountnamesList.addAll(lst_accountName );
            
    List<Case> cas = Trigger.new;
    
    List<Integration__c> listAll = [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,account__c,integrationwith__c FROM Integration__c ];
                
    for(Case c : cas  ){
    
       for(integer i=0; i<=listAll.size();i++){
         
          if(listAll.get(i).IntegrationAccount__c.contains(c.Account.Name)){
                
                                                                                                  
                     String name = listAll.get(username__c);
                     String pwd = listAll.get(password__c);
                     String url = listAll.get(URL__c);
                     
                   
                  
          }

      }
   }
}
```

How can I get the only matched account field value on case with any of the records in Integration__c, then return the record  details from that record only?

when i saving the above code it shows an error called :

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: username__c at line 32 column 48

Comment: The error message seems pretty obvious, no? Did you check that a field with that API Name exists?

Comment: yes i checked with the API names but no change in error

Comment: This code looks identical to several other posts including: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167038/help-to-matching-the-two-different-object-records

Comment: @Adrian yes i'm only asking that question but that answer isn't satistfy my requirement

Comment: But why is your code almost identical? This is very suspicious behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are retrieving `Integration__c` records through SOQL query and storing into `listAll`.

Now you are looping into `for` loop index by index with this code

```
for(integer i=0; i<=listAll.size();i++){
```

> **Issue** is `String name = listAll.get(username__c);`

In the above line you are supposed to retrieve the userName__c attribute's value from Integration__c object. Correct!

To do that, correct code will be `listAll.get(i).username__c;` where `listAll.get(i)` will return object and then from that object you will get the username__c attribute value.

The corrected logic will be like this:

```
String name = listAll.get(i).username__c;
String pwd = listAll.get(i).password__c;
String url = listAll.get(i).URL__c;
```

**or**

```
String name = listAll[i].username__c;
String pwd = listAll[i].password__c;
String url = listAll[i].URL__c;
```

Here is the logic to compare value in the `for` loop and retrieve the data in the `for` loop without using index by index.

**Updated the if condition based on commments**

```
List<Integration__c> listAll = [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,account__c,integrationwith__c FROM Integration__c ];

for(Case c : cas  )
{
    for(Integration__c intObj:listAll)
    {
        if(intObj.IntegrationAccount__c = (c.Account.id)){
            String name = intObj.username__c;
            String pwd = intObj.password__c;
            String url = intObj.URL__c;
      }
  }
}
```

Make sense!

Comment: @Thanks for replying Santanu Boral  i tried your code but got this error:   Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Id].contains(String) at line 29 column 12    this line is causing for error:   if(intObj.IntegrationAccount__c.contains(c.Account.Name)){

Comment: You need to compare properly considering datatype, find the updated logic and change according to your requirements

Comment: i updated the code like this : if(listAll.get(i).IntegrationAccount__r.Name.contains(c.Account.Name)){                                                                                                                                      now i'm not getting any errors at compile time but when i created a new case  above details page shows this exception : Apex trigger Type caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Type: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0: Trigger.Type: line 30, column 1

Comment: Rather compare with the id, instead of name as name can be duplicate, I have already updated in the answer,  please check

Comment: i got this Exception when creating a case abobe details page it shows :  Apex trigger Type caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Type: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Integration__c.IntegrationAccount__r: Trigger.Type: line 30, column 1     for that  add "cIds" object at the end of query again i get this exception System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: i see u r code in if condition i modified like this :                  if(intObj.IntegrationAccount__c.contains((c.Account.id))){  now i get Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Id].contains(Id) at line 29 column 20

Comment: thanks for keep supporting i tried but i'm confuse when comparing case related account and Integration object IntegrationAccount__c.

Comment: If your issue related to question got solved, can you pls accept this answer, so other members can find this useful